# horizontal menu with horizontal submenu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an horizontal menu with horizontal submenu. I've tried something but it didn't work : the code above was supposed to display the horizontal main menu , when you hover on one of the links the color of the link changes and an horizontal submenu appears.

html code:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>

        <li style="float: left; a:hover;  "><a   href="acceuil.html"    style="color : #CBCAC7 ;">ACCEUIL</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="decoupage/puce_menu.png"   height="15"/>
        <ul>
        <li style="float: left; display: none; "><a href="#">Présentation</a>  </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li style="float: left; "><a href="methodologie.html" style="color   : #CBCAC7 ;" >METHODOLOGIE</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="decoupage/puce_menu.png"   height="15"/>
        <li style="float: left; "><a href="references.html" style="color :   #CBCAC7 ;">REFERENCES</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="decoupage/puce_menu.png" height="15"/>
        <ul>
    <li style="float: left; display: none; "><a href="#">Urbanisme</a></li>
    <li style="float: left; display: none; "><a href="#">Tours</a></li>
    <li style="float: left; display: none; "><a href="#">Bureau</a></li>
    <li style="float: left; display: none; "><a href="#">Commerce</a></li>
    <li style="float: left; display: none; "><a href="#">Logements</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
        <li style="float: left; "><a href="partenaires.html" style="color :       #CBCAC7 ;">PARTENAIRES</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="decoupage/puce_menu.png" height="15"/>
        <li style="float: left; "><a href="contact.html" style="color :          #CBCAC7 ;">CONTACT</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="decoupage/puce_menu.png" height="15"/>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
#menu
{ position: absolute;
right: 550px;
bottom: 460px;
z-index: 2;
font-style: italic ;
font-size: large ; 
}

#menu li.hover ul { 
display: inline;}
```

Comment: This article might help (disclaimer: this is my own article!!) - http://www.techfoobar.com/2011/pure-css-multi-level-drop-down-menu-zero-js-code

Comment: I don't want to be unkind, but there are a LOT of problems with this code. Two big tips: get rid of the inline styles and move them to your CSS, then use the [HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options) (use the "Validate HTML Fragment" option on the Direct Input tab to validate just a code snippet) and the [CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input) to spot errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to put `<ul>` element into another `<ul>` element but outside of `<li>` element. It is not allowed, everything should be in `<li>` element, like in `<table>` case, everything outside of `<td>` element breaks the layout.

I would recomment you at first revise the structure of your HTML, then think about the css styles

Answer (score 0):

no js needed: You may float each menu-point as a single `div` in `div` with `overflow:hidden` in a horizontal line. When hovering one of the surrounding divs,
you max up its height, so there is room below for your second horizontal menu, which is already placed inside the `div`.

Also you max up its width, so it gets enough width, to display the second horizontal menu.

Third, you decrease its `z-index`, so the other divs from the main menu can still be hovered and selected, even with the maxed up width of the hovered, active menu-item.